# Google OR-Tools TSP returning several solution

Tags: c#, traveling-salesman, or-tools

I've been recently working on finding more than just the optimal route using Google's OR-Tools. I have found an [example in the repo](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/examples/dotnet/csharp/tsp.cs), but this only solves for the optimal route, any idea how to generate more than just one solution for a set of points? I'm currently working with the DotNet version of the tool, any solution with any other language would be helpful!

```
public class tspParams : NodeEvaluator2
{
    public static int[,] distanceMatrix =
    {
        {   0,  20,  40,   10   },
        {   20,  0,   4,   55   },
        {   40,  4,   0,   2    },
        {   10, 55,   2,   0    }
    };

    public static int tsp_size
    {
        get { return distanceMatrix.GetUpperBound(0) + 1; }
    }

    public static int num_routes
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }

    public static int depot
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }

    public override long Run(int FromNode, int ToNode)
    {
        return distanceMatrix[FromNode, ToNode];
    }
}

public class TSP
{
    public static void PrintSolution(RoutingModel routing, Assignment solution)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Distance of the route: {0}", solution.ObjectiveValue());

        var index = routing.Start(0);

        Console.WriteLine("Route for Vehicle 0:");
        while (!routing.IsEnd(index))
        {
            Console.Write("{0} -> ", routing.IndexToNode(index));
            var previousIndex = index;
            index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", routing.IndexToNode(index));
        //Console.WriteLine("Calculated optimal route!");
    }

    public static void Solve()
    {
        // Create Routing Model
        RoutingModel routing = new RoutingModel(
            tspParams.tsp_size, 
            tspParams.num_routes, 
            tspParams.depot);

        // Define weight of each edge
        NodeEvaluator2 distanceEvaluator = new tspParams();

        //protect callbacks from the GC
        GC.KeepAlive(distanceEvaluator);
        routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(distanceEvaluator);

        // Setting first solution heuristic (cheapest addition).
        RoutingSearchParameters searchParameters = RoutingModel.DefaultSearchParameters();
        searchParameters.FirstSolutionStrategy = FirstSolutionStrategy.Types.Value.PathCheapestArc;

        Assignment solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(searchParameters);
        PrintSolution(routing, solution);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please  read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). In short, your question is to broad with all tags

Comment: Hello @Someprogrammerdude , thanks for the tips. The question is definitely not broad if you have some experience in working with the tool I asked about. The tags are all related because the tool is available in all of the listed languages.

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but there's a function called AddAtSolutionCallback(). According to the documentation, it "adds a callback called each time a solution is found during the search". Maybe you could use that to retrieve the collection of all the solutions found, then you could choose the best ones from this group. Do you think that could work?

Answer (score 3):

Use `AllSolutionCollector` from the underlying CP solver. python code:

```
    solver = routing.solver()
    collector = solver.AllSolutionCollector()

    for location_idx in range(len(data['time_windows'])):
        index = manager.NodeToIndex(location_idx)
        time_var = time_dimension.CumulVar(index)
        next_var = routing.NextVar(index)
        collector.Add(time_var)
        collector.Add(next_var)
    for v in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(v)
        time_var = time_dimension.CumulVar(index)
        next_var = routing.NextVar(index)
        collector.Add(time_var)
        collector.Add(next_var)

        index = routing.End(v)
        time_var = time_dimension.CumulVar(index)
        collector.Add(time_var)

    routing.AddSearchMonitor(collector)

    assignment = routing.SolveFromAssignmentWithParameters(initial_solution, search_parameters)
    if assignment:
        logger.info("solution count: %d", collector.SolutionCount())
        for index in range(collector.SolutionCount()):
            logger.info("solution index: %d", index)
            self.print_solution(data, manager, routing, collector.Solution(index))
        logger.info('final solution:')
        self.print_solution(data, manager, routing, assignment)
    else:
        raise OptimizationInternalException("no solution found")
```

Comment: What is print_solution in this example ? In particular what is the parameter for collector.Solution(index) and how is it handled?

Comment: @KartikAyyar - print_solution is copied from here: https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrp

Comment: Thanks for the example, this is working well. I'd like to better understand what is going on in the two for-loops. It seems this is required in order to access those dimensions later (e.g. when printing the solution), but what is actually happening?