# How to collect more than one solution, Google OR-Tools, TSP

Tags: python, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I am trying to collect more than one solution to the TSP. I am running the Python code in Jupyter Notebook and it is sending all solutions to the terminal (without the routes, just the total distances) but only the optimal solution is being assigned to 'assignment'.

Any help collecting more than the one solution would be appreciated. Cheers.

I have set:

```
search_parameters.number_of_solutions_to_collect = 10
```

According to this documentation: "If 'solutions' is specified, it will contain the k best solutions found during the search (from worst to best, including the one returned by this method), where k corresponds to the 'number_of_solutions_to_collect' in 'search_parameters'."

```
#load the data into a matrix
from __future__ import print_function
import math
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp

def create_data_model():
    """Stores the data for the problem."""
    data = {}
    data['distance_matrix'] = [
        [0, 2451, 713, 1018, 1631, 1374, 2408, 213, 2571, 875, 1420, 2145, 1972],
        [2451, 0, 1745, 1524, 831, 1240, 959, 2596, 403, 1589, 1374, 357, 579],
        [713, 1745, 0, 355, 920, 803, 1737, 851, 1858, 262, 940, 1453, 1260],
        [1018, 1524, 355, 0, 700, 862, 1395, 1123, 1584, 466, 1056, 1280, 987],
        [1631, 831, 920, 700, 0, 663, 1021, 1769, 949, 796, 879, 586, 371],
        [1374, 1240, 803, 862, 663, 0, 1681, 1551, 1765, 547, 225, 887, 999],
        [2408, 959, 1737, 1395, 1021, 1681, 0, 2493, 678, 1724, 1891, 1114, 701],
        [213, 2596, 851, 1123, 1769, 1551, 2493, 0, 2699, 1038, 1605, 2300, 2099],
        [2571, 403, 1858, 1584, 949, 1765, 678, 2699, 0, 1744, 1645, 653, 600],
        [875, 1589, 262, 466, 796, 547, 1724, 1038, 1744, 0, 679, 1272, 1162],
        [1420, 1374, 940, 1056, 879, 225, 1891, 1605, 1645, 679, 0, 1017, 1200],
        [2145, 357, 1453, 1280, 586, 887, 1114, 2300, 653, 1272, 1017, 0, 504],
        [1972, 579, 1260, 987, 371, 999, 701, 2099, 600, 1162, 1200, 504, 0],
    ]  # yapf: disable
    data['num_vehicles'] = 1
    data['depot'] = 0
    return data

def main():
    data = create_data_model()

    # Create the routing index manager.
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['distance_matrix']), 1, 0)

    # Create Routing Model.
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

    distance_matrix = data['distance_matrix']

    def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
        #distance between the two nodes
        # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return distance_matrix[from_node][to_node]

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)

    # Define cost of each arc.
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

    # Setting parameters
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)
    search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = (routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH)
    search_parameters.time_limit.seconds = 1
    search_parameters.number_of_solutions_to_collect = 10 #PROBLEM HERE
    search_parameters.log_search = True

    assignment = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)
#     print(assignment)

    # Print solution on console.
    if assignment:
        # Solution cost.
        print(assignment.ObjectiveValue())
        # Inspect solution.
        # Only one route here; otherwise iterate from 0 to routing.vehicles() - 1
        route_number = 0
        node = routing.Start(route_number)
        route = ''
        while not routing.IsEnd(node):
            route += str(node) + ' -> '
            node = assignment.Value(routing.NextVar(node))
        route += '0'
        print(route)
    else:
        print('No solution found.')

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the answer here [Google OR-Tools TSP returning several solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52074537/google-or-tools-tsp-returning-several-solution)

The following should work:

```py
from __future__ import print_function

from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver.pywrapcp import SolutionCollector


def create_data_model():
    """Stores the data for the problem."""
    data = {}
    data['distance_matrix'] = [
        [0, 2451, 713, 1018, 1631, 1374, 2408, 213, 2571, 875, 1420, 2145, 1972],
        [2451, 0, 1745, 1524, 831, 1240, 959, 2596, 403, 1589, 1374, 357, 579],
        [713, 1745, 0, 355, 920, 803, 1737, 851, 1858, 262, 940, 1453, 1260],
        [1018, 1524, 355, 0, 700, 862, 1395, 1123, 1584, 466, 1056, 1280, 987],
        [1631, 831, 920, 700, 0, 663, 1021, 1769, 949, 796, 879, 586, 371],
        [1374, 1240, 803, 862, 663, 0, 1681, 1551, 1765, 547, 225, 887, 999],
        [2408, 959, 1737, 1395, 1021, 1681, 0, 2493, 678, 1724, 1891, 1114, 701],
        [213, 2596, 851, 1123, 1769, 1551, 2493, 0, 2699, 1038, 1605, 2300, 2099],
        [2571, 403, 1858, 1584, 949, 1765, 678, 2699, 0, 1744, 1645, 653, 600],
        [875, 1589, 262, 466, 796, 547, 1724, 1038, 1744, 0, 679, 1272, 1162],
        [1420, 1374, 940, 1056, 879, 225, 1891, 1605, 1645, 679, 0, 1017, 1200],
        [2145, 357, 1453, 1280, 586, 887, 1114, 2300, 653, 1272, 1017, 0, 504],
        [1972, 579, 1260, 987, 371, 999, 701, 2099, 600, 1162, 1200, 504, 0],
    ]  # yapf: disable
    data['num_vehicles'] = 1
    data['depot'] = 0
    return data


def main():
    data = create_data_model()
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['distance_matrix']), 1, 0)
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

    distance_matrix = data['distance_matrix']

    def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
        return distance_matrix[manager.IndexToNode(from_index)][manager.IndexToNode(to_index)]

    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback))
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC
    search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH
    search_parameters.time_limit.seconds = 1

    # without an initial assignment the CostVar is not available
    assignment = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)
    collector = initialize_collector(data, manager, routing)

    routing.SolveFromAssignmentWithParameters(assignment, search_parameters)
    for i in range(collector.SolutionCount()):
        print(f'================ solution: {i} ================')
        print_solution(data, manager, routing, collector.Solution(i))


def initialize_collector(data, manager, routing):
    collector: SolutionCollector = routing.solver().AllSolutionCollector()
    collector.AddObjective(routing.CostVar())

    routing.AddSearchMonitor(collector)

    for node in range(len(data['distance_matrix'])):
        collector.Add(routing.NextVar(manager.NodeToIndex(node)))

    for v in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        collector.Add(routing.NextVar(routing.Start(v)))

    return collector


def print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution):
    max_route_distance = 0
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
        route_distance = 0
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            plan_output += ' {} -> '.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
            previous_index = index
            index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
            route_distance += routing.GetArcCostForVehicle(previous_index, index, vehicle_id)
        plan_output += '{}\n'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
        plan_output += 'Distance of the route: {}m'.format(route_distance)
        print(plan_output)
        max_route_distance = max(route_distance, max_route_distance)
    print('Maximum of the route distances: {}m'.format(max_route_distance))


main()
```

note that an initial assignment is required first, before enumerating all solutions through the collector, otherwise `routing.CostVar` fails.

Also, all the nodes have to be added to the collector manually otherwise there is a segfault when calling `Solution.Value(...)`. This doesn't seem to be well documented on or-tools site but it seems the collector must have access to all variables which need to be read later via collector.Solution.

Also I think in your code where you used `routing.SolveWithParameters`, there is an optional second argument called solutions which is used to populate solutions found. That is supposed to be a vector, but it does not work with python code.